# Listing SCHEDULED headlines from an org file ordered by date

Tags: org-mode

A few months ago, I converted my init file into an org file, and I’ve
since been using it as a way to [organize my blog posts](http://endlessparentheses.com/init-org-Without-org-mode.html). 
I won’t go into too much detail here, suffice to say that this is a huge
`org-mode` buffer, where many headlines have a `SCHEDULED` date.

**How can I list all SCHEDULED headlines in this file, sorted by date?**

All I care to see is the **date**, **todo status**, and **title**. Anything else is superfluous.
Other important requirements:

- Do **not** ommit headlines marked as `DONE`.
- List **only** `SCHEDULED` items. I don’t want to see headlines
  that just happen to have a date (`<2014-10-04 Sat>`) in them.
- Only use *this* file. Do not search through all my agenda files.

---

For clarity, take the following file.

```
* DONE Hi guys
  CLOSED: [2014-10-04 Sat 15:18] SCHEDULED: <2014-10-04 Sat>
* Hello me
** Hello everyone <2014-10-05 Sun>
** TODO The world is at my feet
   SCHEDULED: <2014-10-11 Sat>
```

I’d like to run a command which would display a list something like this:

```
<2014-10-04 Sat> DONE Hi guys
<2014-10-11 Sat> TODO The world is at my feet
```

Of course, I’m not picky about the format. The important thing is to
have this information displayed in a convenient way.

---

My gut tells me this has something to do with `org-agenda`, but I’m
not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here a way to do it using org-agenda. You can write a custom agenda command like the one below

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("i" "Only scheduled entries in init.org sorted by time" agenda ""
     ((org-agenda-files '("~/.emacs.d/init.org"))
      (org-agenda-entry-types '(:scheduled))
      (org-agenda-start-day "2014-01-01")
      (org-agenda-span 'year)
      (org-agenda-include-diary nil)
      (org-agenda-show-all-dates nil)))))
```

Most of the configuration is happening `settings` part of custom command (I am the skipping the explanation of format of `org-agenda-custom-commands` for brevity, see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>org-agenda-custom-commands<kbd>RET</kbd>). Following is a brief explanation of each of the setting used

1) `org-agenda-files` is set to the init file so that org mode does not search all the agenda files while building this particular agenda.

2) `org-agenda-entry-types` is set to ':scheduled' to restrict it to just to scheduled items.

3)The `org-agenda-start-day` is the day onwards which you want the entries to be listed, I have set it to this years start you might want to set to the day of your first article.

4) `org-agenda-span` tells the numbers days to be included in the agenda view. `org-agenda-include-diary` is set to nil to avoid having diary entries in the agenda view.

5) Finally empty dates are hidden by setting `org-agenda-show-all-dates` to nil.

Now when you run the command `org-agenda` in the dispatcher menu you will get the an option 'i' which you can select to obtain the desired view.

**Old answer**

Use the command `org-occur` from the docstring

> (org-occur REGEXP &optional KEEP-PREVIOUS CALLBACK)
>
> Make a compact tree which shows all matches of REGEXP. The tree will
>   show the lines where the regexp matches, and all higher headlines
>   above the match.

Here is another way to do it. Use occur with a prefix argument. From the docstring of the command.

> (occur REGEXP &optional NLINES)
>
> Show all lines in the current buffer containing a match for REGEXP. If
>   a match spreads across multiple lines, all those lines are shown.
>
> Each line is displayed with NLINES lines before and after, or -NLINES
>   before if NLINES is negative.

So doing <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>occur<kbd>RET</kbd>SCHEDULED<kbd>RET</kbd> should give you what you want

I am not sure how to sort the headlines tough.

Comment: Perfect, I knew org agenda had to have a solution.